# Creating custom calendar in iOS/Swift using EventKit

Tags: swift, eventkit

I am creating a custom calendar using the following code:

```
func createNewCalendar(withName name: String) {
        let eventStore = EKEventStore()
        let calendar = EKCalendar(for: .event, eventStore: eventStore)
        calendar.title = name
        calendar.cgColor = UIColor.purple.cgColor

        guard let source = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents?.source else {
            return
        }
        
        calendar.source = source
        try! eventStore.saveCalendar(calendar, commit: true)
    }
```

But I can't work out how to make this calendar `private` so that it DOESN'T show up in the users other apps, such as the default Calendar app.  Why?  I'm trying to create a calendar of events that is only used by my app.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's what I'm trying to do now. Eventkit.EKCalendar etc all works with the OS so it's impossible use it as a single app's container for your events as I imagine you are trying to achieve this.
It is used tho to create events through your app so users can see it all over the device/applications connected with the user OScalendar.
The answer right now is you need to create a custom calendar with most likely a collectionView and then let the user create "events" (forget about EventKit if u don't want to use the device calendar)to add in an array of "days" so you can store events there and manipulate them.
Hope I explained well.